# C++ Comparing characters with each other

Tags: c++, string

I'm trying to write something where I need to see the individual letters the user enters. For example, a possible input is "HVVHHH". Currently, I want to run through the string one character at a time. So character 0 is H, and it does a command 1 (Right now it just prints the letter). Character 1 is V, does command 2 (Not implemented). Character 2 is V, Does command 2. Etc, etc. Below is what I've written but it returns an error on the `if(...)` line. Returning:

```
error C2446: '==': no conversion from 'const char [2]' to 'int'
```

Can anyone tell me what this means and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream> <string>
int grid[4] = { 1,2,3,4 };
std::string Sequence;

int main() {
     std::cout << "Command: " << std::endl;
     std::cin >> Sequence;
     for (int i = 0; i < Sequence.length(); i++) {
         std::cout << i << Sequence[i] << std::endl;
         if( Sequence[i] == "h" || Sequence[i] == "H") {std::cout << i << std::endl;}
     }
}
```

Comment: You are using the wrong quotes: `"` is for string literal `'` is used with character literals.

Comment: You want `'h'`, not `"h"`.

Comment: I am sure there are many duplicates for this one. Not sure if we should look for a duplicate or just close as a typo

Comment: I choose you, typochu.

Comment: You may want to `transform` your `string` `tolower` or `toupper` so you only need to make one comparison.  Search the internet for "c++ string transform tolower".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sequence[i]` is a `char`, where as `"h"` is an array of `char`, as the error message says. What you need is `Sequence[i] == 'h' || Sequence[i] == 'H'`.

Comment: Perhaps an explanation for the `int` part of the error: `no conversion from 'const char [2]' to 'int'` would be good.